# JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer using HTTP Headers

Tags: jersey, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a requirement in which the REST consumer will be sending in the date data in the client or consumer's locale. The HTTP header will be configured to send the client locale information.

The REST server implementation needs to process the Http header and convert the date from the client locale to the UTC format and store the date into the database.

Similarly when returning back the response when there is a date field the reverse operation is expected. This will ensure the consumer sees the same date which was input by the client.

I want to know how I can access the HTTPRequest object OR pass custom parameters to the my implementated JSONSerializer and JSONDeserializer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the ThreadLocal variable to save the information of ServletRequest and then use it anywhere. For example:

**In your filter to get the information you need in request**

```
public class YourFilter implements Filter {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> _date = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static ThreadLocal<String> getDate() {
        return _date;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        //....
        //other code
        //get the date from request
        Date date = request.xxxxxx();
        //set the date to the local thread variable
        _date.set(date);
    }
}
```

**Use the ThreadLocal variable in your JSONSerializer**

```
@Override
public void serialize(String resourceIdMsg,
                      JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                      SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
    String date = YourFilter.getDate().get();
}
```